# Combining Masonry with Waitforimages, image loading

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, waitforimages

I noticed while testing Masonry that if I shift-reload in Firefox (to hard reload), then the layout would be off by the height of any image in the page.  I think the div heights must depend on knowing the image height, which makes sense.

Since I'm already using jquery.waitforimages.js, I added this at the end of my page and my script:

```
$wall.waitForImages(function() {

    $wall.masonry( 'reload' );

});
```

Although everything works, now I have an error that I see in Firebug, which only occurs if I **don't** hard-reload.  So I'm assuming this error happens when the image is already cached:  "cannot call methods on masonry prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'reload'".

Is there a way out of this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:  Use the script called imagesLoaded with Masonry, since the same author wrote both & they work together.
Script: https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded/

In your jQuery, something like:

```
    $wall = $('#mydiv');
    $wall.imagesLoaded(function(){
            // call your layout function, something like:
            // layoutBricks();
    });
```

This should help avoid the Heisenbug.  I have not tested this new image loading script on my other gadgets, so I don't know about that yet.